# Saving the return of an SQL query, in string arrays, doesn't work with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I tested the query on SQL Server and it works, but not on C#. The error messages point towards the storing mechanism for the variables returned by my query, but I am thinking it is probably the query itself that is the issue.

In Delphi, there is a way to debug query statements (`showMessage` statement).

For example:-

```
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select FIRSTNM, LASTNM, STREET, STREET2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, MEMBERKEY, MEMBID, BIRTH' +
        ' from MEMBER' +
        ' where MEMBID = ''' + Mem_ID + ''''
       );
showmessage(DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL[0]);
```

***Is there a way to do something similar in C# ?
Could anyone take a look and let me know why the SQL query doesn't work in ASP.net but works in SQL Server?***

```
// initialize
string [] HPCODE = new string[20] ;
string [] OPFROMDT = new string [20] ;
string [] OPTHRUDT = new string [20] ;

// Second SQL Query to find out eligibility information about the requested Member. // 
SqlConnection Connection1 = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.SqlServerConnection);
String strSQL1 = "SELECT MEMBER, HPCODE, convert(varchar, OPFROMDT, 101) as OPFROMDT, convert(varchar, OPTHRUDT, 101) as OPTHRUDT FROM [main].[dbo].[MEMBER] INNER JOIN [main].[dbo].[MEMBHP] ON MEMBER.MEMBERKEY = MEMBHP.MEMBERKEY and opthrudt >= opfromdt INNER JOIN [main].[dbo].[HPCONTRACT] ON MEMBHP.HPCODEKEY = HPCONTRACT.HPCODEKEY INNER JOIN [main].[dbo].[LOB] ON HPCONTRACT.LOB_KEY = LOB.LOB_KEY where MembID = @memID";
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(strSQL1, Connection1);
//command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memID", memID);

// SQL reader variable is set.
SqlDataReader Dr1;
// Connection is explicitly opened.
Connection1.Open();
// Reader is executed.
Dr1 = command1.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;

while (Dr1.Read())
{
//    if (memID == Dr["MEMBID"].ToString() )
//     {
// store subID in the Global variable called ID.

    HPCODE[i]   = (Dr1["HPCODE"].ToString()).TrimEnd();
    OPFROMDT[i] = (Dr1["OPFROMDT"].ToString()).TrimEnd();
    OPTHRUDT[i] = (Dr1["OPTHRUDT"].ToString()).TrimEnd();

    i = i + 1; 
//     }
}

// Reader variable must always be explicitly closed to prevent memory leaks.
Dr1.Close();
```

**Error:**

> *Index out of range Exception unhandled by user code:=HPCODe*

**NOTE:-**  
`Parameters.AddwithValue` is uncommented because it is predefined in my previous part of the code. If the solution was that easy, I would have fixed it myself.***

Comment: Holy horizontal scrolling, Batman!  What doesn't work? What is the error message? And do you really mean to have `//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memID", memID);` commented out?

Comment: "holy horizontal scrolling, Batman" hahahaha! great user name too bobby! =).

Comment: I actually have the Parameters.AddWithValue predefined in a previous SQL Query, so that is why I have it commented out.

Comment: if you have commented that out shouldnt you also remove the WHERE statement from your SQL query... ?

Comment: Do you guys even read what I have written abt this commenting and uncommenting part of the Parameters.AddValues??

Comment: @Philosophia sorry... Couldn't see straight there for a second.  I torched my incorrect answer.  Glad you got it!

Comment: Your question was most likley marked down because you didn't mention the parameter in question was declared outside of the code provided, and didn't even give any error messages to start with. All people had to go on was `The error messages point towards the storing mechanism for the variables returned by my Query, but I am thinking it is probably the Query itself that is the issues.` <shrug>  Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: A quick google search of "Index out of range Exception" would have solved your problem pretty quickly....

Comment: and what makes you think I didn't try this

Comment: `// Reader variable must always be explicitly closed to prevent memory leaks.` Considering you ignore the fact that `SqlDataReader`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` all implement `IDisposable`, I think calling `Close` is the least of your "leak" worries.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: `Dispose`ing them. Preferably indirectly, via `using`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// initialize
string [] HPCODE = new string[20] ;
string [] OPFROMDT = new string [20] ;
string [] OPTHRUDT = new string [20] ;
```

You have more than 20 rows returning, so you are erroring when trying to fill the 21st row in your loop.  This isn't a SQL issue; it's a coding issue.

As a quick fix, you can do the following.  However, you may want to make a class to hold your information if it's all related and make a `List` of that class.

```
// initialize
List<string> HPCODEs = new List<string>();
List<string> OPFROMDTs = new List<string>();
List<string> OPTHRUDTs = new List<string>();
```

In your loop, you'd want the following:

```
HPCODEs.Add((Dr1["HPCODE"].ToString()).TrimEnd());
OPFROMDTs.Add((Dr1["OPFROMDT"].ToString()).TrimEnd());
OPTHRUDTs.Add((Dr1["OPTHRUDT"].ToString()).TrimEnd());
```

Comment: the first person who actually saw the error, and my question was marked down for all the wrong reasons, way to go guys. and thank you zim

Comment: So how can this be fixed ?